# How to verify academic history and degree?

Tags: university, degree, academic-history

**TL;DR:** How does one verify the academic credentials (degree earned, date of graduation) of an individual without their permission or knowledge.

---

I'm trying to verify the academic history and degree of an individual. I'm new to verifying academic histories and achievements, so understanding the process and responses below would be very helpful to me (and likely others in the same situation).

The individual states he attended University Maryland University College (UMUC) form 1992 to 1995, and earned a MBA degree. Its public information and published in his Linkedin profile.

I attempted to verify though UMUC's alumni services. The alumni service did not respond to my emails or calls. Next, I called the registrar at the University and they instructed me to go to degreeverify.org. degreeverify.org directed me to the [National Student Clearinghouse](http://www.studentclearinghouse.org).

I placed an order for the verification with the National Student Clearinghouse. It cost me 10 or 20 dollars. I received a "Thank you" email from them and an email address to use in the future (degreeverify@studentclearinghouse.org).

I believe I am getting a run-around from National Student Clearinghouse. After a few days, I sent an email to degreeverify@studentclearinghouse.org requesting the results. National Student Clearinghouse responded back *"The verification results you received came directly from the school and they based their research on the information you provided in your initial request"*:

[image]

I have ***not*** received results or an answer from UMUC or National Student Clearinghouse. Additionally, the National Student Clearinghouse stated I should *"fax or email a copy of the students transcripts or diploma for verification [sic]"*. That's what I paid National Student Clearinghouse to do!

I used National Student Clearinghouse's website "Contact Us" page to request their phone number so I could speak with someone. In addition, I made the same request via email. I have not received a reply to the request for their telephone number!

I'm new to verifying academic histories and achievements, and I surely don't understand the run-around I am getting from UMUC and National Student Clearinghouse. My questions are:

- Why won't UMUC provide me with a Yes/No answer to the Verify operation?
- Why won't National Student Clearinghouse provide me with a Yes/No answer to the Verify operation?
- Why won't National Student Clearinghouse provide me with a telephone number to speak with them?
- Is this run-around typical for folks who verify academic history and degree?
- Do I have any additional options to to verify the academic history and degree?

I'm beginning to wonder if National Student Clearinghouse is a legitimate service. I know National Student Clearinghouse is not BBB accredited. I discovered that after the run-around began.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are snooping into the UMUC graduate's education history behind their back?

Comment: @Mad Jack - yes, but its not really snooping. Its public information on Linkedin. I can provide the URL if you'd like. Would you like it added to the question?

Comment: It could be useful information (not the link to LinkedIn, but that you seek to verify someone's education background without their knowledge). If it were on the "up and up," so to speak, then you could just have the individual have their former academic institution send you a certified transcript, which is not plausible in your case.

Comment: @Mad Jack - unfortunately, I can't ask this fellow. I'm doing research for a lawsuit. He and his company owes me $56,000 in unpaid wages over a 3 1/2 month period. Once the lawsuit is filed, I will have the power of subpeona and will be able to acquire it without him.

Comment: @Mad Jack. And to be clear: I'm only interested in verifying the public information - the dates and the degree. I'm not really interested in classes, instructors, GPA, etc. I believe that would require a release form.

Comment: I added a tl;dr that makes it clear that the distilled version of this question does ask questions involving generalizable knowledge concerning academia.

Comment: Good point. I'll let you do that edit since you're the OP.

Comment: Did you try UMUC alumni services?  They have their directory online at http://alumni.umd.edu  and also 
http://www.umucconnect.org/s/710/index.aspx   .  But otherwise I'd suggest hiring a private investigator or lawyer. This is pretty standard ops for them and it helps keep you at arms length.

Comment: @RoboKaren - yes, I tried the alumni services last week (both phone call and email). No answer from alumni services. When that failed, I called the registrar office to see if there was a list published online. That's when the college sent me to National Student Clearinghouse.

Comment: rots 'o ruck with this, jww.  i wonder how many professors there are claiming, but not holding, particular academic credentials like the PhD.  it ain't zero.  i, personally, do not see the PhD as a "union card" for teaching in a college or university setting, but with the glut of PhD's out there, most institutions **do** require a PhD before they would consider anything else.  because of that, i am convinced there are PhD frauds out there, and the harder it is to independently verify, the more fraud that turns up.

Comment: -1 For  "**without** their permission or knowledge". You could just ask him.

Comment: @scaaahu: The comments make it clear that this isn't an option as it's an adversarial situation (lawsuit).

Comment: @scaaahu - its also verifying public statements. The person in question stated it in his Linkedin profile. He has no reasonable expectation of privacy when he made the public claims.

Comment: @NateEldredge  I am not a lawyer. I don't know enough about what the OP is trying to do. I don't feel that this site is a good place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Employers normally insist that applicants submit official transcripts, sent directly from their universities, making it rather easy to verify their degrees.  I don't think it's likely that many professors have managed to fake their way through this.  The OP's situation is very different as he/she does not have the subject's consent.

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to do is rather unusual.  In most cases where a degree needs to be verified (admissions, jobs, etc), the person doing the checking has the subject's consent, and normally the subject would just have the university send an official transcript.  In that case the university's "customer" is their own alumnus and they have some interest in being responsive.  In contrast, they have no particular incentive to be responsive to you, and so I'm not too surprised that the process they have is not particularly convenient.

That said, I don't see what you can do except to keep following up with NSC and using their support system.  Or, you could get your lawyer involved, and see if a letter from her can speed things along.

I would note that, while federal privacy laws *allow* universities to release "directory information" including dates of attendance and degrees, as far as I know, nothing actually *requires* them to do so.